# Find parent for child value in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html-table:

```
<table id=mytable>
<tr>
<td>
Mark
</td>
<td>
Susan
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Somewhere from javascript an event occur and I can will be able to fetch the name, which is one of those in the table.
From javascript/jquery I need to find the td-element containing the name and color it.
I tried with:

```
$("#mytable").find("td:contains('Mark')").parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

But the td-element doesnt get colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to try this:

`$("#mytable").find("td:contains('Mark')").css('background-color', 'red');`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wvm7tthq/1/)

OR

`$("#mytable td:contains('Mark')").css('background-color', 'red');`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wvm7tthq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You already selected the `td` what you did is you tried to add a color to the `tr` which is the parent of the selected `td`:

```
$("#mytable").find("td:contains('Mark')").css('background-color', 'red');
```

that's why you example should be highlighting both `td` as the color applied for the `tr`